# Tracking input change in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm learning alpine.js and trying to capture the user input value.
I have used "x-on:input" but its not calling the function

Below is the simple form input

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" x-on:input.debounce="validateEmail($event)" x-model="userEmail" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
```

and this is the basic method in my index.js

```
function validateEmail(event){
console.log(userEmail);

}
```

The function is not getting called.

Adding a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-alpinejs?file=index.html)

Please Guide

Thanks
Shruti Nair

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for `x-on:change`

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" x-on:change.debounce="validateEmail($event)" x-model="userEmail" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
```

You'll also want to make your function read the value from `$event.target.value`

Since you've already got an `x-model`, you could add `$watch('userEmail', (val) => {})` to `x-init` and validate that way.

Edit: (based on the stackblitz)

- `x-data` is missing
- I've inlined all the logic from index.js
- forked stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-alpinejs-prwaeg?file=index.html

Full component:

```html
<form x-data="{
  userEmail: '',
  validateEmail(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  },
  submit($event) {
    console.log(this.userEmail)
  }
}">
  <input type="email"  class="form-control"
    x-on:change.debounce="validateEmail($event)"
    x-model="userEmail"
    id="email"
    aria-describedby="emailHelp"
    placeholder="Enter email"/>
  <button type="button" x-on:click="submit" class="btn btn-block">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: :Will you please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-alpinejs?file=index.html

Comment: @ShrutiNair I've updated the answer see https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-alpinejs-prwaeg?file=index.html